# React-table V7 sort column on button click

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-table, react-table-v7

I am following the example here [Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-frog-evtjy) and by default I can sort each column by clicking on each header. If I have a table like the following:

| score | firstName | lastName |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Anne | Faith |  |  |
| 10 | Bob | Smith |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

I want to sort them using a separate dropdown component with options:

- Sort score from high to low
- Sort score from low to high
- Sort first name from high to low
- Sort first name from low to high
- Sort last name from high to low
- Sort last name from low to high

How do I do this using react-table v7?

Answer (score 0):

The [useSortBy docs](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useSortBy) has the methods you can use for this: [`toggleSortBy` and `setSortBy`](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useSortBy#instance-properties).

> `toggleSortBy: Function(ColumnId: String, descending: Bool, isMulti: Bool) => void`
>
> > This function can be used to programmatically toggle the sorting for any specific column

> `setSortBy: Function(sortBy: Array<Object<id: columnId, desc: Bool = true>>) => void`
>
> > This function can be use to programmatically set the sortBy for the table instance.

[Here's a fork of the setSortBy sandbox to give you an idea of how to use these methods.](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-hooks-38ut1)